# Wix - Keep Folders after uninstall

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.5

I want to create an installer using Wix that copies a certain file to the folder 
"**C:\Users\Your User\Documents**\Visual Studio 2010\Addins\"

When I write the following code:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="PersonalFolder">
      <Directory Id="VS2010" Name="Visual Studio 2010">
        <Directory Id="VSAddins" Name="Addins">
          <Component Id="VSAddin" Guid="Some Guid">
            <File Id="MyAddin.Addin" Name="MyAddin.Addin" DiskId="1" Source="..\Resources\" />
            <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='SOFTWARE\ABCD\MY_Addins'
                           Type='string' Value='MY_Addin'
                           KeyPath='yes' />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
```

I get the following compilation error:

ICE64: The directory VS2010 is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.

How can I overcome this error?

I know that i can add the following code inside the "Component" scope:

```
<RemoveFolder Id="VS2010" On='uninstall'/>
```

But I don't want the uninstall to delete folders that i didn't create (Especially the Visual Studio 2010 one...)

Thank you for your help,
Maxim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May I ask why you are putting it in the users's profile instead of installing it for all users?  I find per-user components create all kinds of servicing problems downn the road.  Instead, for my IsWiX project I deploy my AddIn to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\AddIns.

You can take a look at the full source at [IsWiXAddInMM.wxs](http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56616#841593)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider that option indeed.
What about UsersDocuments\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates? 
I need to copy some files in there as well.

Comment: Take a look at the WiX VSExtension.  They have some predefined searches such as VS90_ITEMTEMPLATES_DIR.  Personally I have a different installer that targets 2005 / 2008 and I lay the files down to the main installdir then use CopyFile elements to duplicate the files to the VS directories if they exist.  Then I use an EXE custom action to call devenv /setup if it exists.